# Webpack Dynamically Require Module in Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Say I have the following higher order component:

```
const FormFactorSensitiveWrapper = function(Component, styleFilePath) {
  // if a style file path is given it means we want to require the style file, appending the device type in the path
  // (i.e. the path might come in as 'styles/performer', so dependent 
  // on the compilation type - desktop vs. mobile - this might
  // be expanded to 'styles/performer.desktop' or 'styles/performer.mobile')
  if (styleFilePath) {
      var formFactor = process.env.formFactor;
      require('styles/' + styleFilePath + '.' + formFactor);        
  }

  const FormFactorSensitive = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
          return <Component {...this.props} formFactor={process.env.formFactor} />
      }
  });

  return FormFactorSensitive;
};
```

with usage of said component as follows:

```
FormFactorSensitiveWrapper(Home, 'pages/home');
```

The goal of the above being the dynamic switching of a styling file to require with a module dependent on whether we're compiling a desktop vs. mobile specific bundle.

While this approach works - barely - I get non-fatal warnings in bundle compilation + an extremely bloated chunk as webpack is seemingly unable to determine context and is instead compiling all files in the `style` folder into that chunk. I've tried an approach using `require.context`, but that had separate failures (loaders defined in my `webpack.config.js` didn't seem to be applying appropriately).

**EDIT** I should note that the following also results in the same issue (meaning, usage of environment variables aren't causing the problem):

```
const FormFactorSensitiveWrapper = function(Component, styleFilePath) {
  if (styleFilePath) {
      require('styles/' + styleFilePath + '.desktop');        
  }

  const FormFactorSensitive = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
          return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
  });

  return FormFactorSensitive;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that the problem is the dynamic require path, try using the more verbose mode:

```
if (styleFilePath) {
  switch (styleFilePath) {
    case 'blue':
      require('styles/blue.desktop');
    case 'red':
      require('styles/red.desktop');
  }
}
```

Of course this means that all your styles are imported into this file, which is what webpack is doing anyway by creating a [require context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) that is trying to require all the possible combinations for the dynamic expression (`'styles/' + styleFilePath + '.desktop'`)

If you want to use [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) you would need to use `require.ensure` in webpack 1 or `System.import` in webpack 2.

Comment: hm, yeah I think you're solution would work, however in practice this will lead to really messy code for my use case (since it would require the higher order component to know all possible paths which might be required)

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "messy" code. In reality the component from your example might not know all the possible paths but the implicit knowledge is spread across your application, otherwise how do you know if a path is available or not?

Comment: Forgot to add, take a look at [webpack contexts](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) and its [example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs).